# PPTP linux server - Linux clients ok - Windows client can't connect to some web servers

Tags: windows, debian, vpn, pptpd

I have one mysterious problem with our VPN office server. I have installed PPTP server on Debin 6 Squeeze and enabled forwardind, because I need to connect to some servers with our office IP address. Everything works like a charm when I am connecting from Linux client (Ubuntu and Android). I can access office server and services on this server and I can connect to all server on the internet with my office IP address. But when I connect from Windows client (test XP and 7), I can access office server and services and only some servers on the internet. Ping works to every servers, but I can access only some of them.

Here is my config files:

**pptpd.conf**:

```
option /etc/ppp/pptpd-options
logwtmp
localip 192.168.0.2
remoteip 192.168.0.10-20
```

**pptpd-options**

```
name pptpd
refuse-pap
refuse-chap
refuse-mschap
require-mschap-v2
require-mppe-128
ms-dns 8.8.8.8
ms-dns 8.8.4.4
proxyarp
nodefaultroute
lock
nobsdcomp
```

Thanks for your help...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will answer my question myself; this helped:

```
iptables -A FORWARD -p tcp --tcp-flags SYN,RST SYN -j TCPMSS --clamp-mss-to-pmtu
```

From the [poptop mailing list](https://lists.sourceforge.net/lists/listinfo/poptop-server) and [LARTC](http://lartc.org/howto/lartc.cookbook.mtu-mss.html).